# creating a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, regression

My data is set up as so:

```
site    date      amb   ppm1   ppm2   ppm3   time0   time1   time2   time3
A       5/6/12     350   370    380   385     0       3        6       9
```

I need it in a format with 2 columns (one being concentration and the other time)

```
conc   time
350      0
370      3
380      6
385      9
```

So that I can run a regression on it. Or help with how to run a regression on the original set up would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Using your sample data, and assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf", you can use `stack` for each "set" of columns to get the output you show:

```
setNames(data.frame(stack(mydf[, grep("^ppm|^amb", names(mydf))])[-2], 
                    stack(mydf[, grep("^time", names(mydf))])[-2]), 
         c("conc", "time"))
#   conc time
# 1  350    0
# 2  370    3
# 3  380    6
# 4  385    9
```

- `grep` was used, just as an example for if you have many similarly named columns and don't want to count to identify their column indexes. If this is truly representative of your data, `stack` could also just be `stack(mydf[, 3:6])[-2]` and `stack(mydf[, 7:10])`.
- `setNames` is just a convenience function to rename the column names in the output.
- The `[-2]` just removes the second column from each `stack` command (which is a column of the column names from which the values were taken).

---

Another option, if you don't mind changing the variable name of "abm" to "ppm0" would be to use `reshape`:

```
names(mydf)[3] <- "ppm0"
reshape(mydf, direction = "long", idvar = 1:2, 
        timevar = "measure", varying = 3:ncol(mydf), sep = "")
#            site   date measure ppm time
# A.5/6/12.0    A 5/6/12       0 350    0
# A.5/6/12.1    A 5/6/12       1 370    3
# A.5/6/12.2    A 5/6/12       2 380    6
# A.5/6/12.3    A 5/6/12       3 385    9
```

You can, of course, drop the first three columns very easily.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is a single vector:

```
> mydata <- c("A", "5/6/12", 350, 370, 380, 385, 0, 3, 6, 9)
```

your names added:

```
> names(mydata) <- c("site", "date", "amb" ,"ppm1","ppm2","ppm3","time0","time1","time2","time3")
```

would kinda look like you describe above:

```
> mydata
  site     date      amb     ppm1     ppm2     ppm3    time0    time1    time2    time3 
  "A"  "5/6/12"    "350"    "370"    "380"    "385"      "0"      "3"      "6"      "9"
```

and to transform it you could just do:

```
> data.frame(conc=mydata[3:6],time=mydata[7:10])
```

which would result in

```
       conc time
  amb   350    0
  ppm1  370    3
  ppm2  380    6
  ppm3  385    9
```

Comment: That's a pretty major assumption you make, that the data are a single vector. As can be seen in your example input, everything there has been coerced to characters, while they are not in the OPs data.

Comment: @AnandaMahto this was just the way I try reproduce the data structure of OP, he did not specify where he copies the data imput from. if the quotation marks are bothering, you can add them as `factor`. I only add this in case it might be as simple problem as that, an alternative.

Comment: No problem. Having alternatives is always good. My point was mainly that you're making a big assumption in your answer. Unfortunately, the OP seems to have been a hit-and-run user, so we may never know the truth about the actual structure of their data :)

Comment: Also, just a heads up, I generally avoid naming objects `t` as that may introduce confusing code for people who commonly work with matrices and need to `t`ranspose their data. Functionality, for the most part, is not affected, but legibility might be.

Comment: you have a point there ... I just quickly wrote it up ... I think naming objects and functions the same should not do any harm in R .. but to avoid confusion I will change the names in the answer =)

Comment: In case you're interested, [here's a discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/conversation/variables-with-function-names) from a couple of months ago on the topic. Both linked questions are also interesting.

Comment: cool, i just read it and in fact there are some good points made and tips suggested, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use regular expressions to split the string to get your two vectors (concentration and time). And if you are using R, you create a data frame simply by calling

```
data.frame(concentration=concentration,time=time)
```

on your two vectors.